# Changing style of all same class name of elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I got this error. And I can't find what was wrong with it. I am using PHP and javascript.

I have a hidden iframe below my code:

```
<iframe id="hidden_form_submitter" name="hidden_form_submitter" style="width:100%;height:1px;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
```

And I have this line of code, an action button in which the `id` of a row will send as URL parameter:

```
<tr bgcolor="#d1ffcf" class="row-<?=$transaction['id']?>">
<td>
    <a class="done-btn" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="?action=change&status=done&transact_id=<?=$transaction['id']?>" target='hidden_form_submitter' title="Click if matched!"> Done</a>   
</td>
</tr>
```

Then lastly I have this code on top to update the row in my database:

```
<?
if($_GET['action'] == 'change'){

    //update query here

    echo "<script>window.parent.document.getElementsByClassName('row-{$get['id']}').style.backgroundColor='green';</script>";

    exit;
}

?>
```

No problem on the updating side in my server. 
The problem is the JavaScript wherein  I want to change the bgcolor of all same class without reloading the whole page.

UPDATE: Cannot change the background of every class. Example, I have this parameter to be send. `?action=change&status=done&transact_id=1608`
So all element with class `row-1608` should change the background color or change something style.

Comment: just try to remove {} in your javascript

Comment: Trying removing it is a synthax error on my editor.

Comment: Changing it to `'row-".$get['id']."'` gives me same error.

Comment: what is your class name?

Comment: Class name is depend on the id in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
echo "<script>window.parent.document.getElementsByClassName('row-{$get['id']}').style.backgroundColor='green';'</script>";
```

To this:

```
echo "<script>";
echo "var allRows = window.parent.document.getElementsByClassName('row-{$get['id']}');";
echo "for (var i = 0; i < allRows.length; i++) {";
echo "    allRows[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';";
echo "}";
echo "</script>";
```

You need to iterate `allRows` and set the `backgroundColor` on each element.

(Inspired by this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbyclassname_loop))

Comment: Well, removing the extra `'` gives me new error `Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined`

Comment: @c.k I think I found what your problem was, can you check my updated answer?